# R Select rows based on condition in another column

Tags: r

How can I select all the rows of those IDs, that have at least one B as Item?

```
df<-cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),c("A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A"))
colnames(df)<-cbind("ID","ITEM")
df
```

Comment: `library(dplyr);df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(ITEM == "B"))
`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but:

```
df[df[, 2]=="B", ]
```

Comment: thx, but please read my specification:I select all the rows of those IDs, that have at least one B as Item, for this example it means: give me all rows for ID 1 and ID 2 (but no rows for ID 3, because ID 3 has no B in any Item). your query just results in all rows with a B.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you construct a data frame rather than working with a list.

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),ITEM=c("A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A","B","A","A"));

df %>% filter(ITEM == "B");
```

Comment: thx, but please read my specification: select all the rows of those IDs, that have at least one B as Item, for this example it means: give me all rows for ID 1 and ID 2 (but no rows for ID 3, because ID 3 has no B in any Item). your query just results in all rows with a B.

Comment: right answer is given by  Ronak Shah